# Update Values in Excel using Apache POI Jar

Tags: apache-poi

My Scenario is like i want to download Excel from our Application, which contains n number of rows. After downloading the Excel i want to update datas into the excel using poi jar. The problem here is when i manually creating the excel and try to update the excel cellvalues at that time it is working fine, But after downloading the Excel i am trying make changes at the time its not updating the values.. No error message in console..

I think it will be in read only mode.. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Without any code, it's going to be very hard to work out what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Please show your code for download,read and modify excel. Otherwise it is tough to help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but changing an already downloaded Excel file from the server side is generally impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was using wrong one. Using poi jar it's possible to read/write.